# Integrating $\exp (\exp (x))$

Tags: calculus, integration

How am I able to integrate $e^{e^x}$?

$$\int e^{e^x}dx$$

Am I suppose to use $u$ substitution?  But what should I let $x$ be?  And what should $dx$ be?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you think this is possible?

Comment: You cannot always hope for an easy solution. Many functions lack a primitive function which is *elementary*.

Answer (score 16):

The answer will not be given in terms of elementary functions. If we denote $u=e^x$, then $dx=u^{-1}du$, and so your integral becomes the so-called [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)
$$\int \frac{e^udu}{u}=\mathrm{Ei}(u).$$